# JFace, SWT Change comboviewer width when input changed

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have two comboviewer and the idea is that the second combo will display a subset of options depending of the first combo value selected. But after to set the new input in the second combo and refresh the combo width is too small. How can I set it for auto adjusting to options width?

```
public class ExpresionDialog extends Dialog {
    private ComboViewer combo1;
    private ComboViewer combo2;

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite composite) {
        Composite parent = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(composite);
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 2, 1);

        combo1 = new ComboViewer(parent);
        combo1.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
        combo1.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
        combo1.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent e) {
                IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) e.getSelection();
                AttributeOption option = (AttributeOption) sel.getFirstElement();
                combo2.setInput(getValuesCombo2(option));
                combo2.refresh(true);
            }
        });
        combo1.setInput(getValuesCombo1());

        combo2 = new ComboViewer(parent);
        combo2.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
        combo2.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        return parent;
    }

// Omitted getValuesCombo1 and getValuesCombo2 methods ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `layout` method of the parent `Composite` to get it to redo the child layouts each time you change the contents.